# Python insert to mysql table not working

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql table called Games which i'm attempting to store data i'm retrieving from a metacritic API. The schema for the table is the following.

```
CREATE TABLE `Games` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `metacriticURL` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `rlsDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `metacriticRating` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metacriticScore` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I'm getting the following error when attempting to insert data to the table with the MySQLdb API:

> OperationalError(1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row
>   1")

Here is the relevant code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", 
                     user = "root",
                     passwd = "secretpassword",
                     db = "GamesDB")
cur = db.cursor()
insertQuery = 'INSERT into Games (name,
                                  metacriticURL,
                                  rlsDate, 
                                  metacriticRating,
                                  metacriticScore,
                                  platform) VALUES (%s %s %s %s %s %s)'
insertData = ('Game Name', 'http://www.website.com/some/path', datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-11-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 'M', '74', 'ps4')
cur.execute(insertQuery, insertData)
```

I'm catching the error further down and see the error message string from above. I've been debugging this for quite a few days and all the values look just fine right before the execute call. There are 6 values from my insertData and there are 6 columns I'm declaring in my SQL query string, so i'm not sure how the column counts don't match. I've put hard-coded values in my code example above just for this post.

Any insight/thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this (%s, %s, %s, %s,  %s, %s) ?

```
insertQuery = 'INSERT into Games (name,
                                  metacriticURL,
                                  rlsDate, 
                                  metacriticRating,
                                  metacriticScore,
                                  platform) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

Comment: Wow, I seriously left out the commas between the values like you have here.... *facepalm* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `InsertQuery` is erroneous on `%s`, It should be written as:

```
insertQuery = "INSERT into Games (name, metacriticURL, rlsDate, metacriticRating, metacriticScore, platform) 
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
```

Comment: Not according to [MySQLCursor documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: But it does seem to explain the problem. On the other hand, if *mysqldb* does not provide quoting, does it provide escaping? Or is it vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: An input coming from user makes any Mysql query vulnerable, you can apply `mysql_real_escape_string` on values in `insertData` to be on a safer side.

Comment: If that is right, it is disappointing. I assumed that the API which separates parameters was designed in order to do exactly that: quoting and escaping. Anyway, one more reason to stick with an orm